# Removing class from div doesn't stop jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have a div with the class "item". When I use .removeClass('item') on the div, it doesn't stop it's jquery function from going. Here's my code:

```
<div class = "item">
   //stuff in here
</div>
```

And the jquery:

```
$(".item").mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).find(".clear").show();
});
$(".clear").click(function() {
   $(this).closest("div").removeClass('item');
});
```

When I remove it's class (and I am removing it successfully, I tested it with some css) it still responds to the jquery code. How can I make it so that it won't respond to that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind) the event handler.

Use

```
$(this).closest("div").removeClass('item').unbind('mouseenter');
```

---

Alternatively you can bind the initial event to a container element (*or the `document`*) and delegate to it the handling. This way it will indeed not react to clicks once the class has been removed.

Using 1.7 methods

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.item',function() {
   $(this).find(".clear").show();
});
```

Using 1.6 and below methods

```
$(document).delegate('.item','mouseenter', function() {
   $(this).find(".clear").show();
});
```